# Почему height:100% не работает в данном случае?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот у меня есть контентная часть, которую я с помощью стиля 'flex' расположил автоматически между хедером и футером(в нем пока нет контента), мне нужно расположить секцию welcome до конца экрана, я прописываю 'height': 100%, но ничего не происходит, почему так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Answer (score 2):

Потому что по высоте не бывает 100% от экрана, может быть 100% от родительского элемента, а экран в высоту в браузере не ограничен, там условно бесконечная прокрутка.

Comment: я не верстальщик, но мне кажется, что это зависит от значения свойства `position`, если `relative` - то процент от родительского элемента, `absolute`,`fixed` же будут считаться либо от размеров экрана, либо от размеров документа.

Comment: Нет, позиция это начало отсчета где будет располагаться элемент. 100% означает относительный размер, и если родитель есть - то родителя - если нет, то экрана. Но в высоту нет размера экрана

Comment: ставь хэдер 20vh(например), а основной 80vh и будет тебе счастье. Либо у боди ставим 100vh, а эти блоки уже в % выставляем